# Some strings on Chinese locale are truncated in SWT Label in Eclipse RAP on the first dialog opening

Tags: java, swt, chinese-locale, eclipse-rap

After reloading this effect disappears and labels are in their suitable sizes. This repeats only if the application is reloaded. On English locale, this dialog shows normally.
[image: Chinese text truncation]

Example of code containing problem label:

```
private void createDailyGroup(Composite composite)
{
    m_typePanels[DAILY] = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
    Composite panel = m_typePanels[DAILY];
    panel.setLayout(GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(3).create());
    panel.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().create());

    addRunTime(panel, DAILY);
}
 private void addRunTime(Composite panel, int scheduleType)
{
    Label runTimeLabel = new Label(panel, SWT.NONE);
    runTimeLabel.setText(QmfResources.getString(IDS_RUNTIME_LABEL));
    runTimeLabel.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().
        align(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER).grab(false, false).create());
    m_runTimes.put(Integer.valueOf(scheduleType), new DateTime(panel, SWT.TIME | SWT.BORDER | SWT.SHORT));
    DateTime runTime = m_runTimes.get(Integer.valueOf(scheduleType));
    runTime.addSelectionListener(m_parametersChangeListener);
    runTime.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().align(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER).create());
}
```

Comment: Calling pack() on the label or composite doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, here I am considering runTimeLabel is label where you want to add Chinese locale string

```
runTimeLabel.getParent().requestLayout();
runTimeLabel.getParent().redraw();
runTimeLabel.getParent().getParent().update();
```

Comment: If possible provide more information on your code. As similar issue we had for German text which we solved. May you are not calling layout for correct composite. You can use layout() method too.